For EM algorithm, why we assign an independent distribution $Q_i$ for each sample index
I'm learning the expectation maximization algorithm with Andrew's CS229 lecture notes https://pillowlab.princeton.edu/teaching/statneuro2020/notes/notes18_LatentVariableModels.pdf
The derivation and proof for monotonically improvement is pretty clear to me, but I'm curious about one particular assumption used in the derivation.
In deriving the lower bound, we tweaking the log-likelihood estimation by introducing an new distribution $Q$ over latent variable $z$:
\begin{aligned}
\sum_{i} \log p(x^{(i)}; \theta) & = \sum_{i} \log \sum_{z} p(x^{(i)}, z^{(i)}; \theta)\\
&= \sum_{i} \log\sum_{z} Q_{i}(z^{(i)}) \frac{p(x^{(i)}, z^{(i)}; \theta)}{Q_{i}(z^{(i)})}\\
&\geq \sum_{i} \sum_{z} Q_{i}(z^{(i)}) \log \frac{p(x^{(i)}, z^{(i)}; \theta)}{Q_{i}(z^{(i)})}
\end{aligned}
and there would easy to that the $Q(z)$ can be estimate using posterior density
\begin{equation}
Q_i(z^{(i)}) = p(z^{(i)}|x^{(i)}; \theta)
\end{equation}
My question at here is this, in the notes, there is a valid distribution $Q_i$ over $z$ for each $i$, where $i$ is the index over the sample set. So for each  sample $x^{(i)}$ it's latent variable $z^{(i)}$ would be drawn from an independent distribution. I don't understand why this is needed, and when we estimating $Q_i(z^{(i)})$, it actually dependent on the same distribution $p(z|x; \theta)$, so would there be any difference if we don't assume independent $Q_i$ for each $z^{(i)}$ ?
